# Java - make a function to create a variable with the name = String we input?

Tags: java

How can i make a function:

When i input a string "abc" this function create a variable with the same name, like this: `int abc = 10`.

```
void func("abc"){
..........
}
//I will have: int abc =10;
```

I can't do it, someone help me?

Comment: This is impossible in Java, as you can't have variable/dynamic variable names as in PHP.  Why not just store the name-value pair in a `Map` instead?

Comment: Why would you need this, as opposed to just using a variable name that's appropriate for any input or using a map if you absolutely need to associate some value with that string?

Comment: @delnan probably to complete some homework :D

Comment: how do you think with pointer in java?

Comment: Java doesn't have "pointers" in the C sense of the word. Based on what you are describing, you need to use a Map<String, Integer>.

Comment: @FloppyDisk: inner anonymous class?

Comment: No, Maps are part of Java's default collections library. You would use something like Map<String,Object> = new HashMap<String,Object>(); See smas answer for more details on the maps stuff and look at the java api docs for Maps.

Comment: From what you have told people here, Map is definitely what you are after- you would however really benefit from telling people here what you are trying to achieve as well. The context may help resolve an underlying misunderstanding

Answer (score 4):

You can't create variable in such dynamicly way in Java. But you can use a `Map<String, Object>`, which allow you support what you need. Try this:

```
public class DynamicVariableUtil {
    private Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    public void setVariable(String name, Object value) {
        map.put(name, value);
    }
    public Object getValue(String name) {
        return map.get(name);
    }
    ...
}

dynamicVariableUtil.createVariable("abc", 10);
...
dynamicVariableUtil.getValue("abc");
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but **very**  tricky. I do not think you really need what you are describing. What you really need is method (please, not function!) that returns int value, i.e.

```
int func(String str) {
   return str.length();
}
```

Now you can use this method:

```
int i = func("abc");
```

this method will return 3.

If you really want to create in variable into method so that this variable will be accessible outside the method you can use JDI (Java debugging interface). You can connect to the JVM where your application is running and do almost anything. But again, I think that this is not what you really need.

Comment: Oh, i wana have a variable with the same name of the string.